# Running script on IFTTT interaction update on my Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm in a very specific situation. I'm working on a complexe project, I can't give all the details here. But to make it simple, I'm tracking an RSS feed using IFTTT. Each time the feed is updated It add a new row in my Google Sheet. I've build a Google Apps script on this sheet and I would like to trigger it for each new row added. I've tried trigger `on Interaction` and `On Change` but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks.

edit: I finally add the fake count formula on my spreadsheet somewhere and it seems to work :)

Comment: You can make use of a webhook. Send it the web app url that you set up with apps script. Use function doGet(e) to run the update every time you get an update via the webhook. I don't know if the IFTTT webhook is easy to use, but I found this article: https://www.marcus-povey.co.uk/2012/11/07/using-webhooks-with-ifttt-com/

Comment: Other solution solely in Apps Script is to run a trigger every five minutes and save the current spreadsheet and check if there were updates

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at the webhook but sound heavy for what I need to do. and yes about triggering every five minutes but I really need to make it trigger for reach update. but at that point, if there is no other solution I'll have to rewrite the all script.